# Got fatal error 1236 Slave has more GTIDs than the master has, using the master's SERVER_UUID

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, gtid

We are testing replication using GTID's on two servers running MySQL 5.6. Replication was running fine, but now it is not functioning. When I run `show slave status\G` on the slave, I get the following error message

> Last_IO_Errno: 1236 Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master
>   when reading data from binary log: 'Slave has more GTIDs than the
>   master has, using the master's SERVER_UUID. This may indicate that the
>   end of the binary log was truncated or that the last binary log file
>   was lost, e.g., after a power or disk failure when sync_binlog != 1.
>   The master may or may not have rolled back transactions that were
>   already replica'

I have tried to reset master and stop, reset, and restart slave, with no luck, and cannot find any information about this particular issue online.

Oddly, when checking `show slave status\G` on master, I get a different error.

> Last_Errno: 1007 Last_Error: Error 'Can't create database 'repltest';
>   database exists' on query. Default database: 'repltest'. Query:
>   'create database repltest'

But when I check both the slave and the master, the database 'repltest' does not exist. This was just a database we created on master to check that replication was working, and we deleted it from the master afterward.

Edit - Note: this is a staging environment that does not have active database connections from any applications. This was set up merely to test replication with GTIDs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to restore the slave based on the procedure outlined on this [blogpost](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/02/08/how-to-createrestore-a-slave-using-gtid-replication-in-mysql-5-6/). Once replication is fixed, you may then want to run [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) and [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html) to synch data between the two servers.